# Converting day and month variables into Numerical values (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have data on online job postings, but with some variables structured as string when I want them to be numerical to create time series graphs as in [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/tstsline.pdf).

The three variables I am interested in converting into numeric variables look as follows:

```
dataex month posted_date revenue
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str10 month str19 posted_date str32 revenue
"March_2021" "2021-03-08 10:44:15" "Less than $1 million (USD)"      
"March_2021" "2021-03-08 10:44:15" "Less than $1 million (USD)"      
"Dec_2020"   "2020-12-13 08:04:59" "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Nov_2020"   "44150.33611"         "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Dec_2020"   "2021-01-04 04:59:40" "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Nov_2020"   "44167.24444"         "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Dec_2020"   "2020-12-16 10:49:38" "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Nov_2020"   "44167.24514"         "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Nov_2020"   "44172.01319"         "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"Dec_2020"   "2020-12-30 05:52:25" "$10+ billion (USD)"              
"April_2021" "2021-04-21 04:16:12" ""                                
"April_2021" "2021-04-21 04:16:12" ""                                
"Feb_2021"   "2021-03-01 01:03:09" ""                                
"Feb_2021"   "2021-03-01 01:03:09" ""                                
"Feb_2021"   "2021-03-01 01:03:09" ""                                
"April_2021" "2021-04-21 05:57:59" ""                                
"April_2021" "2021-04-21 05:57:59" ""                                
"Dec_2020"   "2020-12-22 08:13:06" "$500 million to $1 billion (USD)"
```

I would like the new variables to look something as below:

```
month_n posted_date_n revenue_n 
02/21   09/02/21       $500m_1B
03/21   14/03/21       +10B
04/21   11/04/21       +1m
```

So based on the instructions [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-quickly-convert-many-string-variables-to-numericvariables/), I ran the following code:

```
// Destring variables string variables with numerical values 
gen posted_date_n = real(posted_date)
gen month_n = real(month)
gen revenue_n = real(revenue)
```

However, I could not really get what I am looking for and instead, the data looks as follows:

```
dataex revenue_n posted_date_n month_n
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(revenue_n posted_date_n month_n)
.        . .
.        . .
.        . .
. 44150.34 .
.        . .
. 44167.25 .
.        . .
. 44167.25 .
. 44172.01 .
.        . .
.        . .
.        . .
```

Comment: See `help datetime` for functions to turn string variables into numeric datetime variables. Your first variable is doable. For the second variable it would be necessary to know what the other values like "44150.33611" mean. For the third variable you can look at `recode`.

Comment: Values like "44150.33611" are Excel's Date:time format (e.g. this is 2020-11-15  8:04:00 AM I believe)

Comment: `real()` on string dates only works well exceptionally, e.g. if years have been imported as strings by mistake.

Comment: Sorry `recode` is only for numeric variables, so maybe just look at `replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run code to get the data into almost the form you wanted, *but not for the date values like 44150.33611, etc.* These seem to be excel format as noted by @JR96.

I recommend using the split function and a really handy write up by Nick Cox is a useful read ([source](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/splitting-string-variable/)).

```
// Month/Year
split month, p("_")
drop month
rename month1 month
gen month_n = date(month,"M")
format month_n %td_Month
rename month2 year
destring year, replace
format year %ty
rename year year_n

// Posted Date
split posted_date, p(" ")
drop posted_date
rename posted_date1 date
rename posted_date2 time
gen posted_date_n = date(date, "YMD")
format %tdNN/DD/CCYY posted_date_n
```

This doesn't do exactly what you ask for but it's closer than nothing in my opinion. Example output as,

```
month_n, year_n, posted_date_n
March, 2021, 03/08/2021
March, 2021, 03/08/2021
```

Where everything is formated as a date that Stata can recognize. Maybe someone else can jump in here on combining the `month_n` and `year_n` column?

Comment: No need to split anything here. OP can use `gen month_n = monthly(month, "MY")` and `gen posted_date_n = dofc(clock(posted_date, "YMDhms"))` which then could be formatted as `%tm` and `%td`, respectively.

Comment: Nice that's pretty good. I would recommend you submit your code as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I would but it seems as though they have abandoned ship on their question...